# How to place div in top right hand corner of page

Tags: html, css

How do you float a div to the top right hand corner of a page using css? I want to float the `topcorner` div which is below:

```
<p><a href="login.php">Log in</a></p>

<div class="topcorner"><a href="home.php">Back to Home</a></div>
```

"Log in" goes in the left hand corner which it does at moment, but I want "Back to Home" to be placed in the other corner.

Comment: any css?? how about jsfiddle it?>

Answer (score 154, accepted):

the style is:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .topcorner{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
  }
</style>
```

hope it will work.
Thanks

Comment: This seems to position the div in upper-right corner of higher-level (probably positioned) parent div, not the upper-right corner of the browser chrome.

Answer (score 29):

Try css:

```
.topcorner{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right: 10px;
 }
```

you can play with the `top` and `right` properties.

If you want to float the `div` even when you scroll down, just change `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

You can use css `float`

```
<div style='float: left;'><a href="login.php">Log in</a></div>

<div style='float: right;'><a href="home.php">Back to Home</a></div>
```

Have a look at this [CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css">
 .topcorner{
  position:absolute;
  top:10;
  right:15;
  }
</style>
```

You ca also use this in CSS external file.

Comment: What's different to this answer than the first one? Besides the top:10 and right:15... Duplicate answer... Downvoted