# keeping div at the top right corner of browser window - Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-position

I can keep a div on the left side of the browser window with this css:

```
.foo {
  position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:999;
}
```

The div will always appear at the top-left of the browser window even when the window is scrolled.

Now I would like to have the div kept on the right side of the browser window, but this didn't do the job (in Safari):

What should I be doing?

**Answer**

The answer is to add `float: right`, e.g.:

```
.bar {
  position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; z-index:999; float: right;
}
```

Other browsers may not need it.

Comment: could you provide your HTML structure.

Comment: Only an idea, set realtive to the body element or form element, inside the body, set  <div style="position:relative;top:0;right:0;"></div>

Comment: turns out I just needed to add `float: right`

Comment: Beware! float:right; may behave differently in different screen sizes

Answer (score 1):

```
.bar {
  position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; z-index:999;
}
```

There is no reason why this wouldn't work. Change the z-index to a higher or lower value than the other fixed elements. If this does not work please provide more information like your html structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
```

Which was found on the following question:

[How to place div in top right hand corner of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231329/how-to-place-div-in-top-right-hand-corner-of-page)

In your case, changing fixed to absolute might fix it? Let me know how you go, as their may be another way todo this in safari.

Comment: When using `absolute` the div scrolls when the page scrolls. I want the div to stay at the same position within the browser window even when the page is scrolled.

Comment: Yeah that's true...Weird that it's not working on Safari though? Anyway you found the fix! @ErikR