# Why aren't the endpoints of my boxes meeting evenly (div positioning)

Tags: css-position

[Picture of positioned div's using css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SDf9.png)

based on the css that i wrote using absolute position, I thought the boxes would meet evenly on the ends but the blue box is not flush with the yellow box. Is there a rule that i'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Add `top: 0;` and `left: 0;` to class `blue`. By default they are being set to `top: 8px` & `left: 8px` causing the overlap.

```css
.blue {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.yellow {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

.red {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: why isn't top: 0; and left: 0; added to yellow class and red class?

Comment: @Lagoon top & left are position of the boxes within the screen. They are not added because they are positioned at a different location correctly ie., yellow at 200px & red at 200px .

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your blue class

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

This may help more as well: [How to place div in top right hand corner of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231329/how-to-place-div-in-top-right-hand-corner-of-page)